# woocommerce правильный ЧПУ

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, чпу

необходимо что бы ссылки на категории и товары были следующего вида:

```
/shop/category/ - Ссылка на категорию
/shop/category/product_name/ - ссылка на товар в категории
/shop/category/subcategory/ - ссылка на подкатегорию если она есть
/shop/category/subcategory/product_name/ - ссылка на товар если он в подкатегории
```

Сейчас работает с категориями, а как сделать с подкатегориями?

Сейчас прописан следующий код в functions:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array',  'rewrite_shop_base');
function rewrite_shop_base( $rules ) {
    $shop_base = 'market';
    $new_rules = array(
        $shop_base . '/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        $shop_base . '/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );

    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Мне будет достаточно даже если будет возможность вручную для нескольких категорий содержащих подкатегории прописать правила. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поставьте плагин Yoast SEO, там все это удобно.

Comment: @labris не нашел там такие настройки

Comment: Может быть, Yoast не то, что нужно для решения вашей проблемы. Посмотрите также тут - http://wpincode.com/dobavlyaem-podkategorii-v-postoyannye-ssylki-v-woocommerce/

Comment: Этот костыль может в будущем больно ударить. Незачем вообще удлинять ссылки. А путь к товару нужно обозначать хлебными крошками. И они к структуре УРЛа не имеют никакого отношения.

Comment: Я считаю что путь товаров должен быть таким же как и путь категорий. И во многих других CMS это нормально. Впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой((